# EC2 instance in public subnet has no public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have created a *VPC* and within I created a *Subnet* and a *Internet Gateway* (attached to the VPC). In that subnet, I created a Route Table in which I set route 0.0.0.0/0 to target the *Internet Gateway*.

After that I launched an EC2 instance in my subnet but it has no public IP so I can't connect to it using RDP.

I tried to enable '*DNS hostnames*' and '*DNS resolution*' but it didn't add a public IP to my instance (even after restarting it). In my subnet, I enabled '*Auto-assign IPv4*' but still no public IP.

Any clue what I'm missing here please?

Comment: There's default limit of 5 Elastic IP addresses per region, did you check that?

Comment: I'm not making use of any Elastic IP and don't want to if I can do without

Comment: Did you enable 'Auto-assign IPv4' *after* launching the EC2 instance? It won't take affect retroactively.

Comment: @jarmod Yes. But then I restarted the instance so it shouldn't be an issue I guess?

Comment: That setting matters at launch time, and only at launch time. Changing it afterwards has no impact. Stopping and restarting doesn't change that. Anyhow, the key thing is that you cannot attach a (non-EIP) public IP after launch. So, either attach an EIP or capture an AMI of the instance and launch a new instance, this time requesting a public IP at launch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your instances won't automatically get public IPs attached to their ENIs after you enable 'Auto-assign IPv4' in your subnet. One possible solution without spinning up a new EC2 is to attach an Elastic IP (as @Oleksii Donoha suggested in the comment) to this instance. You can follow the aws docs to [allocate an Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-allocating) and then [associate it with your running instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-associating).

Side note: It's not possible to attach an **ephemeral** ip to an already-created ENI or EC2 instance. See discussions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/706560/assign-public-ip-not-elastic-ip-after-instance-launched).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I would like to avoid using Elastic IP since it is a limited ressource. Do you know the technical reason preventing me from getting an ephemeral IP even after enabling "Auto-Assign IPv4' and restarting the instance?

Comment: Ok so I created a new EC2 instance AFTER setting 'Auto-assign IPv4' now my instance got a public IP I can connect to. This behaviour seems weird to me and would appreciate some explanation : why restarting the instance isn't enough?

Comment: @Mit94 Restarting the instance won't work because the public IP is actually determined by the underlying ENI and restarting the instance won't change it. Just think of ENI as a virtual network card. The root problem is AWS doesn't let you add ephemeral  IP to primary ENI after creation.

Comment: @Mit94 Auto-assign IPv4 is a subnet level default setting that gets *copied to* the instance's ENI's attributes at instance launch assuming you don't override it then.  It's copy, not inherit, which is why the behavior seems confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Though your instance sits in public subnet, you have to make sure that 'Auto-assign Public IP' is either set to 'Enable' or 'Use subnet setting (Enable)'on Configure Instance Details page. Sometimes folks forget to check/reverify this setting while creating EC2 instances.

Comment: How do I get to that page? Or is it only available when creating the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue after VM migration process from another vendor. Solved by creating disk snapshot -> image -> new instanse from the image -> public IP assigned automatically.